# Angular addEventListener from factory

Tags: angularjs

Inside my service I have a factory for controlling HTML5 audio. I'm trying to pass through the variable "loaded" to my controller. My controller isn't detecting any change and therefor gives me the value "false". Is there a way I can detect a change and passthrough the right variable? Thanks for the help.

This is de code I'm using:

```
angular.module('app.services.playerService', [])
    .factory('Player', ['$document', function($document) {

        var audio = $document[0].createElement('audio');

        var player = {

            getStatus: function() {

                var loaded = false;

                audio.addEventListener("loadstart", function() {
                    console.log("Starting to load audio");
                    loaded = false;
                });

                audio.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
                    console.log("Starting to load audio");
                    loaded = true;
                });

                return loaded;

            }

        };
        return player;

    }]);
```

Comment: I don't understand how you are using this. Can you put the code of your controller?

Comment: I'm trying to get different states in my player so I know when my audio is loading or playing etc. At this point I have no code in my controller only checking if the variable loaded is passed through "console.log(Player.getStatus());".

Comment: From what I see from your code, you will always receive `loaded = false` from your code. `loaded` has already been returned when `loadstart` or `canplay` are fired.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to fix but can't find a way.

Comment: The solution depends on what are you using this for. You could use `$broadcast` to propagate the event to your scope and then listen for it in your controller, or you could change `loaded` so that it is `player.loaded` instead of being returned. Did you have a look at [ngAudio](https://github.com/danielstern/ngAudio/blob/master/app/angular.audio.js)?

Comment: ngAudio is perfect. Thank you.